# Web Chat : Bot not able to communicate to bot application server

Tags: automation, botframework, chatbot

I have registered a bot on Microsoft chat framework. I have the chat application deployed in one of the public servers and configured with the registered chat bot.

Able to access the chat application from emulator and is working fine. But when I try to access it from web chat Frame or Skype, it says "couldn't send, retry"

Please help, resolving the issue
[Screenshot of Channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HzCU.png)

Comment: Are you developing with .NET or Node SDK? Please post your code that is causing the issue.

Comment: If you click on the Issues(5) link, what are the errors?  Do you have the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword set correctly in your deployed bot?

Comment: What endpoint do you have configured in the bot portal?

Comment: Am using Node SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem: HTTP status code InternalServerError, you can go to the azure website, and create a bot application, then program the bot on the website (you can use the old code that you used in VS), I don't know why, I programmed the bot using VS, and published it on azure, but it doesn't work (can work in bot framework emulator but can't use web chat and direct line), so I try to go to azure website, I found out that code on the website one still default code.